# How to generate a string by pairing a map's keys and values?

Tags: java, dictionary, foreach, lambda, concatenation

The below is a pseudo example of what I'm attempting:

```
String parameters = "";

context.forEach((k, v) -> {
    parameters = parameters + k + "=" + v;
});
```

Any ideas on how to get `parameters` to contain the indicated string?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a [`String`-joining `Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--) like so

```
String result = context.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

assuming you don't want a separator. Otherwise, provide an appropriate delimiter to the [`Collectors#joining(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) call.

Comment: Sweet - Works like a charm - Thanks!